# How to perform an operation at a specified rate

Tags: python

I have a function that I want to call, say, 10 times per second. I start out with code like this:

```
while True:
    the_operation()
    time.sleep(1.0/TIMES_PER_SECOND)
```

This works ok but the_operation is called slightly less often than desired, because the time to do the operation itself. We can make the code look like this instead:

```
while True:
    t = time.time()
    the_operation()
    time_to_sleep = 1.0/TIMES_PER_SECOND - (time.time() - t)
    if time_to_sleep > 0:
        time.sleep(time_to_sleep)
```

This is better, but still not good enough -- the time to execute the loop is not considered, and if the_operation happens to take significantly longer than 1/TIMES_PER_SECOND in one iteration, our throughput will be too low. The operation on average takes less than 1/TIMES_PER_SECOND, but the code needs to handle the cases where it does take longer.

What is a good pattern for calling the_operation at the specified rate?

Comment: Neither of the duplicates work if the operation sometimes takes longer than the timeout.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46352009/how-to-perform-an-operation-that-takes-a-variable-amount-of-time-while-maintaini